# Teradata case statement

Tags: case, teradata

Hi i am using the below query where i need to print value 'Yes' if a particular column  has a value .in the below example for particular case id there are two values (one with proper date and one with NULL) so the result should be 'Yes' but i am getting two results 'Yes' and 'No'.Please find below the case statement.

```
select 
   distinct CC.CASE_ID,
   case when CC.L2CALL_BK_SCEHDULED_PST_DT is not NULL 
        then 'Yes' 
        else 'No'
   end as L2_OUTB_CAL_SCHD_FL

FROM EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE   CC
INNER JOIN EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE_EXTN CCE
ON CC.CNTCT_CASE_APND_KEY = CCE.CNTCT_CASE_APND_KEY
INNER JOIN EDW_STAGE_COMN_SRC.STG_CNTCT_CASE_DELTA  DELTA
on CC.CASE_ID = DELTA.CASE_ID
where 
CC.CASE_ID='22922029' 
group by 1,2
```

Comment: You need to do a `MAX(CASE...` and `GROUP BY 1`

Answer (score 0):

Moving from a comment by @dnoeth:

> You need to do a `MAX(CASE...` and `GROUP BY 1`